# Database hosting, control from RPi python console

Tags: sql-server, hosting, self-hosting

I tried a free account in pythonanywhere.
Hosted a free mysql database.
Created a database.
They have a online python console in which we should control mysql, I want to control it from my python raspberry Pi console, is this even possible?
I tried to connect, but it failed.

My ultimate aim is to get data from raspberry Pi and store it in a real time database, the data base should be controlled from my python program.
Suggest me any better way...
This is a part of my project, not any commercial thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of security reasons, databases are generally never open to the internet. (eg: https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/hc/en-us/articles/205408088-Access-Your-Database-Remotely-Through-an-SSH-Tunnel)

PythonAnywhere has it setup so that you need to use ssh tunnelling to connect to your db from an external place.

See https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/SSHTunnelling/

What you need to do is

```
ssh -L 3306:mysql.server:3306 username@ssh.pythonanywhere.com
ssh -L 3333:mysql.server:3306 username@ssh.pythonanywhere.com
```